# Cómo hago para que el control del formulario no cubra completamente la columna porque se ve muy ancho,

Tags: bootstrap-5

Me gustaria que quede centrado pero menos ancho, estoy utilizando Bootstrap 5. Es decir que el formulario se vea estilizado en el centro de la pantalla dentro de una especie de container que no cubra toda la pantalla (ancho) a menos que se abra en pantallas pequeñas

```
<body>
  <div class="container mt-5">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
              <h1 class="display-1 text-center">
                  CRUD Fetch API
              </h1>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row mt-3">
          <div class="col-12">
              <form action="">
                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="inpuserId" class="form-label">User Id</label>
                    <input type="text"
                        class="form-control form-control-sm" name="inpuserId" id="inpuserId" aria-describedby="helpUserId" placeholder="User Id">
                    <small id="helpUserId" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
                  </div>
                  
              </form>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

[image: Allí se observa que está bien pero está muy ancho el input]

Comment: y los estilos de la pagina ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realicé dos cambios en los `div` que contiene el formulario

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-6">
              <form action="">
                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="inpuserId" class="form-label">User Id</label>
                    <input type="text"
                        class="form-control form-control-sm" name="inpuserId" id="inpuserId" aria-describedby="helpUserId" placeholder="User Id">
                    <small id="helpUserId" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
                  </div>
              </form>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Asumiendo que haces uso del starter template de Bootstrap 5. El `justify-content-center` para que el navegador pueda definir cómo se distribuye el espacio a lo largo del `container` y el `col-6` para definir un tamaño específico de columnas.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte